# git push to new branch of my friend's account

Tags: git, git-push

I try to work with my co-students for one project. We will work on the same git repository now which is my friends' account. I was successfully pull or clone the origin repository, but I can't create a new branch to push updated files to his git repository. I have error message of following:

---

```
remote: Permission to friend/your.git denied to me.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/friend/your.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

---

> **Is there any setting to give me a permission for my friend's git repository? Or is my code wrong?**

I used the code of following:

```
$ git push origin master:branch
$ git push origin branch
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I couldn't create new BRANCH on his git repo, I don't try to create a new git repository on his account.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your friend to go to `Repository` | `Settings` | `Collaborators`. Then add your email/username as collaborator giving write permission. Now you should have `Push` permission.

[image]